# PWA with FCM cloud messaging

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

Is there blog or working github example of using PWA with FCM cloud messaging.

Tried a few links but getting :

`Abort Error :20
Registration Failed - Push Service Error`

I had setup the manifest.json with gcm_sender_id and service worker   with messagingSenderId

I get this when i try to

```
  serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.subscribe({
                                userVisibleOnly: true
                              }).then(function(sub) {
                                console.log('endpoint:', sub.endpoint);
                              }).catch(function(e) {
                                console.error('error:: :', e.message);
                              });
```

In the call back of

```
navigator.serviceWorker
              .register('service_sw' )
              .then(function(reg ) {
                      console.log('SW: 100');
                        swRegistration = reg;


                          //window.Notification.requestPermission();
                          setTimeout(function(){ 
                            //alert("Hello"); 

                            reg.pushManager.subscribe({
                                userVisibleOnly: true
                              }).then(function(sub) {
                                console.log('endpoint:', sub.endpoint);
                              }).catch(function(e) {
                                console.error('error:: :', e.message);

                              });

                          }, 3000);

                        //initializeUI();    
                    //   console.log(reg);
                  }
              )
              .catch(function(err) {
                  console.log('SW: Error:' +err)
                }
              );
          });
```